# Flutter mlkit Arabic Text Detector

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-mlkit

Hi im using flutter [mlkit](https://pub.dev/packages/mlkit) with [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/) to pick up text from image, everything is ok if the language is English , my problem when the text in image is Arabic , the Text Detector get unknown language

```
P9 Hell bill
olaall dal aJlal SlL acgio prolei
äallall lspall JSail Sasi
aijall ilcllg aigisIil ölall llial aa yuli
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/) the on-device models of ML Kit

> can recognize text in any **Latin-based character set.**

So if you're using the on-device models they won't work with Arabic text as in your screenshots.

One alternative to recognize other character sets is to use [Firebase's cloud-based machine learning model for text recognition](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/recognize-text).

Comment: i use firebase_ml_vision cloudTextRecognizer and it work successfully

Answer (score 0):

With Firbase Vision add this

```
    FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);
    FirebaseVisionCloudTextRecognizerOptions options = new FirebaseVisionCloudTextRecognizerOptions.Builder()
            .setLanguageHints(Arrays.asList("en", "ar", "hi"))
            .build();
```

you need to define any language for example arabic "ar" and so on the most important thing is to go with cloud recognition and have your key on firebase cloud consol then use it in your app

arabic language work only with cloud no offline (on device)

regards